# php check a character on multiple lines of a string

Tags: php, string, replace, strpos

I've got a string coming in which is a multiple line string, depending on the input the format is slightly different

```
 1. Qatar
 2. Qatar
 3 . Cathay
 4. Qatar
 2 . British
 3. Qantas
```

I want the output string to have the same format for all lines:

```
 1 . Qatar
 2 . Qatar
 3 . Cathay
 4 . Qatar
 2 . British
 3 . Qantas
```

I can make it check the first line using

```
$fullstop = substr("$input", 2); //isolate character 2



if (strpos($fullstop, '.') !== false) { //check is the character in pos 2 is a .
$output = str_replace("."," .",$fullstop); //replace the full stop with space fullstop
}
```

This works fine for the first line, however I want the code to do the same for all the lines of code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your strings above all have a blank (space) character before the first digit (eg " 1. Quatar").  Is that a typo?

Comment: just replace `space-dot`s and `dot`s with `space-dot`, right?

Comment: @dtw are you still considering which answer to accept?

Answer (score 0):

`strtr()` will work to replace things:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/830a78d59dededed9b0f6fb7cb0c867f275d8b95))

```
$string='
1. Qatar
2. Qatar
3 . Cathay
4. Qatar
2 . British
3. Qantas';

var_export(strtr($string,[' .'=>' .','.'=>' .']));
```

Output:

```
'
1 . Qatar
2 . Qatar
3 . Cathay
4 . Qatar
2 . British
3 . Qantas'
```

[strtr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) is a great function for this task because it replaces longest matches first, and once a substring is replaced, it will not be replaced again in the same call.  This behavior is why a `space-dot` never becomes a `double-space-dot`.

---

Or `preg_replace()`:

```
var_export(preg_replace('/\d+\K\./',' .',$string));  // digit then dot
//                           ^^--- restart fullstring match (no capture group needed)

var_export(preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\./',' .',$string));  // dot preceded by a digit

var_export(preg_replace('/(?<! )\./',' .',$string));  // dot not preceded by a space
```

Or `str_replace()`:

```
var_export(str_replace(['.','  '],[' .',' '],$string));
```

This adds an extra space before each dot, then "cleans up" by converting any double-spaces to single-spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$output = preg_replace('/(\d+)([.\s]*)/m','$1 . ',$input);
```

[*Live demo*](https://3v4l.org/vSZ2q)

Comment: The `m` pattern modifier does nothing when there are no anchors (`^`, `$`) in the pattern.